# Saber si una fecha esta en el mes actual

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Necesito validar, si el mes actual coincide con un mes de una fecha guardada(una fecha de nacimiento)

Ejemplo:

Fecha 25/11/2020

Fecha de nacimiento: 30/03/1999

En este caso es falso

¿Alguna idea?

Ejemplo de mi data:

```
_id: ObjectId("5fb72a4245494b99847d63c2")
name: "Jose Angel Colin Najera"
age: 21
birthdate: 1999-03-19T06:00:00.000+00:00
```

Ejemplo en JASON:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5fbeaab200318b85c4d8c267"
    },
    "name": "Jose Angel Colin Najera",
    "age": {
        "$numberDecimal": "21"
    },
    "birthdate": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "921823200000"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es bastante sencillo, únicamente se necesita la  palabra reservada `$month` la cual tiene la siguiente sintaxis::

```
{ $month: <dateExpression> }
```

Con eso podemos sacar el mes de cualquier fecha y la convierte en un numero, enero siendo 1 y diciembre 12.

Igual necesitaremos `Date()` para obtener la fecha actual.

Con esto así simplemente es cuestión de hacer lo siguiente:

en un $proyect:

```
{
  mes_actual: {
    $month: Date()
  },
  'mes_cumpleaños': {
    $month: '$birthdate'
  }
}
```

La variable `mes_actual`, tomara el mes en el que estamos de manera numerica, ejemplo:
Noviembre = 11
entonces `mes_actual = 11`
y `mes_cumpleaños` tomara el mes en el que esta la fecha guardada en `birthdate` en este caso:
birthdate: 1999-03-19 -> mes = 03
entonces `mes_cumpleaños = 03`

Luego simplemente preguntamos si son iguales con `$eq`, cuya sintaxis es:

```
{ $eq: [ <expression1>, <expression2> ] }
```

Y listo, comparador de fechas